# Is there a way to wait for a specific event inside a function?

Tags: javascript, events, stimulusjs

I'd like to wait for an event inside a Stimulus controller, like:

```js
displayModal() {
  // wait for turbo:frame-render event
  this.modal.show()
}
```

It seems to me that `.addEventListener` doesn't fit this need, as it'd trigger `this.modal.show()` each time a frame is rendered.

Is there a way to wait for a specific event to be triggered inside a function ?

Comment: Why not call the method you have now when the event you want happens?

Comment: @tomerpacific and how do you wait for the event to happen in order to call the method? Back at square one.

Comment: the event comes from Stimulus library (when a frame is rendered). Other frames can be rendered, and they may not be related to the modal I'd like to show. The only of doing it is to add a event listener and immediately remove it after showing the modal, but it looks quite ugly...

Comment: @VLAZ - there is a way in JS to register for certain events (I.E. on click listeners), so you don't have to "wait" for that event to happen. If there is a specific logic the OP needs, that logic needs to happen inside such a listener.

Comment: @tomerpacific which is what OP is asking for. Maybe with different words but you and I both know that's what needs to happen. What you have is a good start of an answer. What you had *before* wasn't in any way helpful: point was that when the question is "how do run code when event happens" counter-questioning "why not run the code when event happens" isn't exactly helpful. Yes, it's clear to me what an event listener is. But you were just leading OP into a circular solution.